# Removing instance points that share the same coordinate with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a mesh with a junction point (selected vert — shared between 2+ edges) converted to a curve (so the junction point gets separated into several segments) and an instance created on each point:

[image]

Node tree:
[image]

Can I somehow remove *all the instances* that share the same coordinate of the junction points? And keep both `Mesh to Curve` and `Curve to Points` nodes

Scene: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms95uxnop464fed/remove_on_junction.blend?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the instances that have a common point, I would not create an instance at these positions in the first place.

You can solve this by a selection, which you get by determining the number of points per edge:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Amazing — thank you. I was sure I have to use `Vertex Neighbors` but wasn't sure where to plug it